# Error by deploy my discord bot on Heroku. How I can change this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, deployment, discord.py

I want to deploy my discord bot on Heroku but I get an error:

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/EinfachNurBaum/OwO-Bot (from -r /tmp/build_25fc34fd/requirements.txt (line 1))
         Cloning https://github.com/EinfachNurBaum/OwO-Bot to /tmp/pip-req-build-8bavf25j
       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q https://github.com/EinfachNurBaum/OwO-Bot /tmp/pip-req-build-8bavf25j Check the logs for full command output.
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

I think the "requirements" is the problem:

```
git+https://github.com/EinfachNurBaum/OwO-Bot
discord==1.0.1
discord.py
async-timeout
TenGiphPy== 2.5.0
```

Here are my imports:

```py
import discord
import random
import TenGiphPy
from itertools import cycle
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import asyncio
from time import sleep
```

Comment: "*Check the logs for full command output.*" - Please share this/more information.

Comment: You don't need `discord==1.0.1` and  `async-timeout`. The github link leads to a 404 page, that may be why you have this error

Comment: `https://github.com/EinfachNurBaum/OwO-Bot`, is probably a private repo, heroku doesn't have access to it, and thus cannot clone and install it.